# How to use half image on slideshow with html,css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I want to change this code to :

```
<div>
    <div style="width:100%">
        <img src="images/o.jpg" alt="" style="width:100px;height:100px;justify-content: center;padding-left:50%" />
    </div>

    <div id="flipbook">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="content"><a href="#">Flowers: What you didn't know</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="content"><a href="#">Flowers: Real or Fiction?</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="content"><a href="#">A Flower ate my Baby!</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="content"><a href="#">Will Flowers Destroy Earth?</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result is : [image]

How I can change result to : 
[image]

And work for responsive,thanks

Comment: can you show your css or do you use any library to the slide?

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:** In case you use vanilla html/css or you can edit your library-provided css:*

You need to use [`position: relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

*A relatively positioned element is an element whose computed position value is relative. The top and bottom properties specify the vertical offset from its normal position; the left and right properties specify the horizontal offset.*

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nx9hym2g/)'s a working fiddle, and a snippet:

```css
section{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section img{
      border: 1px solid black;
}

#logo{
  top: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/80/80" />
  </div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/200/" />
</section>
```

Comment: I assumed he wanted to edit the css of his library (if he used one). But given the well indented code and the inline-css, it seems to suggests he uses vanilla html / css.